# React elements not sorting on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When updating an array using react state, the value changes but it does not re-sort the react elements that are mapped from it. In this code snippet, the initial state is `[1, 3, 2]`, then mapped to another array, then sorted and displayed like `[1, 4, 9]`. When I add 2 to the last element of the array, the list value changes to `[1, 16, 9]` in the list but the sorting does not change. Can someone please explain why it behaves like this?

```js
const TestObject = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([1, 3, 2]);
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setState([state[0], state[1], state[2] + 2]);
  };
  const mappedArray = state.map((x) => x * x);
  mappedArray.sort();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>State: {JSON.stringify(state)}</p>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      <h4>Sorted:</h4>
      <ul>
        {mappedArray.map((x, idx) => (
          <li key={idx}>{x}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: See the [sort docs, in particular this highlight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#:~:text=The%20default%20sort%20order%20is%20ascending%2C%20built%20upon%20converting%20the%20elements%20into%20strings%2C%20then%20comparing%20their%20sequences%20of%20UTF%2D16%20code%20units%20values).

Comment: sort is not a pure function, It changes the `state` reference. `The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the reference to the same array, now sorted.`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: As mentioned (it's not the issue w/ sorting) mutating state directly is a habit to break early :)

Comment: @S___ See the [sort docs, in particular this highlight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#:~:text=The%20default%20sort%20order%20is%20ascending%2C%20built%20upon%20converting%20the%20elements%20into%20strings%2C%20then%20comparing%20their%20sequences%20of%20UTF%2D16%20code%20units%20values).

Comment: @DaveNewton that helped i.e. if I provide the compare function `(a, b) => a - b` it works as expected. My practical scenario is already like this, but it also does not work. So, I might get another complex example

Comment: The sorting issue in my practical scenario was due to a bug hidden beneath some complexities. The issue with this example is definitely the missing compare function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default `sort` mechanism converts the array elements to strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#:%7E:text=The%20default%20sort%20order%20is%20ascending%2C%20built%20upon%20converting%20the%20elements%20into%20strings%2C%20then%20comparing%20their%20sequences%20of%20UTF%2D16%20code%20units%20values):

```js
const arr = [10, 3, 20, 1]
console.log(arr.sort())
```

To do a numeric sort change the `sort` function:

```js
const arr = [10, 3, 20, 1]
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to change the state reference, which is forbidden, state should only be changed through the `setState` function. `[...state]` will create a new array with a different reference in memory, so state will not change.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState([1, 3, 2]);
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setState([state[0], state[1], state[2] + 2]);
  };
  const mappedArray = [...state];
  mappedArray.map(x => x * x).sort();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>State: {JSON.stringify(state)}</p>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
      <h4>Sorted:</h4>
      <ul>
        {mappedArray.map((x, idx) => (
          <li key={idx}>{x}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in answer by Mrudhula Katta, it is better to pass a compare function `sort((a, b) => a - b)`.This will ensure that code is not sorting array alphabetically.

Comment: While this solves the state mutation problem it doesn't resolve the sorting issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton, hhm, but I see the correct result.

Comment: Define "correct"--it won't sort numerically. The result is the same regardless of whether state is being mutated directly because the `setState` isn't using the current value of the state.